# How can I abort a thread to ensure the application doesn't get stuck?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, thread-abort

Given below is the code that uses a `WorkingBlock` function. The application uses C# 3.0.

The `WorkingBlock` method code works well except in some circumstances with which the application freezes.

Initially, the `WorkingBlock` method was called directly in `CallerFunction`. The following structure was set up to mitigate the issue of the application freezing.

However, even after this, the control will be present inside the `WorkingBlock` method of the `DoAction` `Thread` and the application would still be stuck. I have even tried to set `DoAction.IsBackground` to `true` but nothing works.

Is there a way to forcefully abort the `DoAction` `Thread` so that the application will not be stuck? The control should leave the `CallerFunction` method altogether.

```csharp
private void CallerFunction(Record record)
{
    //some work done
    bool SeeResult = CalledFunction(record);
} 

private bool CalledFunction(Record record)
{
    Waithandles CheckWaithandles = new Waithandle [] {new ManualResetEvent(false), new ManualResetEvent(false)};

    Thread TimeOutCheck = new Thread(() => {
        //Has a StopWatch to check timeout. Thread will stop once StopWatch has reached an Elapsed Limit 
        (ManualResetEvent)CheckWaithandles[1]).Set();
    });

    Thread DoAction = new Thread(() => {
        WorkingBlock(record);
        (ManualResetEvent)CheckWaithandles[0]).Set();
    });

    TimeOutCheck.Start();
    DoAction.Start();

    int WaitHandleCalled = WaitHandle.WaitAny(CheckWaithandles);
    if(WaitHandleCalled == 0)
        return true;
    else
    {
        return false;
        DoAction.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that is possible to be compiled.

Comment: Also, are you sure this is version 2.0 of the C# language? The code uses lambda expressions but they weren't introduced until C# 3.0, back in 2007.

Comment: Do you need Code for 'WorkingBlock'? For situations where the application freezes, it is similar to having the thread sleep for an extended amount of time.

Comment: I mean things like `If(WaitHandleCalled == 0)` aren't valid C# syntax. `if(WaitHandleCalled == 0)` would be. Likewise for `Private void` vs `private void` and `Return true;` vs `return true;`, etc.

Comment: Apologies, I have made the changes.

Comment: I corrected `TimeOutrCheck.Start()` to use `TimeOutCheck` and swapped the [tag:c#-3.0] tag for [tag:.net-3.5] since this isn't really a language question.  Also, `DoAction.Abort();` is unreachable code due to the preceding `return false;`.

Comment: If there is no way to cooperatively cancel the operation performed by `WorkingBlock`, then your best option is to run the whole thing in its own process and then terminate the process. You should **not** terminate threads in an application you intend to keep running, all sorts of bad things can occur.

Comment: @Shalashaska - Aborting threads is only ever useful when you are trying to forcibly shut down your entire app. In every other circumstance you can corrupt the run-time and you can no longer trust any of your other threads are doing the right thing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Could you please provide a resource/example if how to add the thread into a process and then close it to avoid issues with the application running?

Comment: Just for curiousity, would the thread terminate in a clean and safe way of CancellationToken was used (in case c# 4.0 was used) even in this situation?

Comment: @Shalashaska - A `CancellationToken` is a way of performing cross-thread ***communication*** safely. It then allows your thread to inspect the `CancellationToken` to determine if it should shut down or not. It's up to your thread to perform what ever action it needs to co-operate with the request to shutdown. Nothing can force a thread to shutdown.

Comment: @Enigmativity - In such a case, will such a case work well using Tasks (if I was working with 4.0)?
If the WorkingBlock method was causing issues where it prevented the application to continue running, will Using a CancellationToken to a Task terminate it without issue?

Comment: @Shalashaska - I don't think you're understanding the issue. You can't "terminate" a thread or a task. You can only notify the thread or task that you'd like it to end by using a `CancellationToken`. It's up to the thread or task to use that information to shut itself down.

Comment: What can be done in a situation where control is stuck in a method and we need to redirect it away from the method so that the application is not stuck?

Comment: @Shalashaska - You need to create a new Process and run the method there. Processes can be terminated whenever you want.

Comment: I am aware of processes used for Executables and other Program Files.

Is it possible for Processes to be used for a method in an Application?

Can you provide a link or a code example of this? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @Shalashaska - You start an executable when you launch a process. You need to marshall your data back and forth. Starting the process is easy: `var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("filename.exe", "1 2 3"); var p = Process.Start(psi);`. Stopping it is easy and safe - `p.Kill(true);`. Watching it is easy - look at the properties and methods on the instance of `Process`.

Comment: @Shalashaska - There are libraries out there that can help too. But I've not personally used them so I can't recommend one.

Comment: Can you provide the code for `WorkingBlock()` and wherever this occasional freeze is happening?  I think the thing that's still not clear — to me, at least — is whether the place where the `DoAction` `Thread` gets "stuck" in `WorkingBlock()` is external code you don't control or not.  If you control and can make changes to `WorkingBlock()` then _cooperative_ cancellation, as discussed in the comments above, is the way to go: one thread signals to request cancellation, and the `DoAction` thread will check for that signal throughout its lifetime and cleanly tear itself down when needed.